# slide up and down tablelayout

Tags: java, android

I have create table with some rows, and i want it to be slide up and down back automatically every 1 minute.but as my code below it slide up but did not slide down back. So please anyone can help me to solve this, I am not specialize about java, please help and give some example. thanks in advance.

```
TableLayout table01 = (TableLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.table01);
    Animation animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
    Animation animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);



    table01.startAnimation(animHide);
    table01.startAnimation(animShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are applying up and down both animation at the same time. This is the problem . Use `sleep(1500)`  between both animation . If you want repeating animation then use  loops such as `while` or `for`. Run this loop infinity and on the action of user break this loop.

```
table01.startAnimation(animHide); 
 sleep(1500);
table01.startAnimation(animShow);
```

Surround this with `try` and `catch`.